# Handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in a function calling another functions

Tags: node.js, error-handling, axios

I am having problems do handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in a function that call other functions making axios request.

```
const getCode = async () => {
  const code = await baseURL.get('/gcs/login/k?codigoCanal=4')
  return code
}

const posLogin = async (code) => {
  const poslogin = await baseURL.get(`/resource/autenticar/${code}`)
  return poslogin
}

const login = async () => {
 try {
  const code = await getCode();
  const finishedLogin = async posLogin(code)
 } catch (error) {
   handleLoginError(error)
 }
}

const handleLoginError = (error) => {
  if (error.response.status === 400) {
      throw new Error(`Bad Request; ${error.response.statusText}`)
    }
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    throw new Error(`Wrong credentials; ${error.response.statusText}`)
  }
  throw new Error('Unknown Error')
}


login()
```

Executing this code returns me UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, but I realized that if I put a try catch inside the catch of login functionn, this warning disappears

```
} catch (error) {
  try {
    handleLoginError(error)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Ooppss', err)
  }
```

When I do this my code enter in the nested catch and the "err" value is the value of the handleLoginError(error)

How can I do the same without executing a try catch inside the catch?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to call `login` as follows:

```
try {
  await login();
}
catch(err) {
  // handle here the error
}
```